# Type to text input using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Here's my code:

```
locationEl.value = "Something automatically typed";
evt = document.createEventObject('KeyboardEvent');
evt.keyCode = 32;
locationEl.fireEvent('onkeypress', evt);
```

Error is

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'document.createEventObject('KeyboardEvent')')
```

What could be wrong here or otherwise what is the correct way to trigger type events (keypress events) text into a input element.

Comment: javascript has a class for it
object.onkeypress = function(){myScript};

Comment: Hey xybrek, were you able to solve this problem in the end?

Comment: @Vaviloff yes the problem was solved

Comment: I was more interested in the way that it was solved rather in knowing it just was :) What was the reason of the error and if the answer below helped the resolution.

Comment: @Vaviloff yes I will post the answer here soonest

Answer (score 0):

The code you want to call in context of the web site you are manipulating should be placed in `page.evaluate` function handler. Instead of using `KeyboardEvent` to simulate keystrokes try setting the input element value:

```
page.open("https://..........", function(status) {
  if (status === "success") {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      document.querySelector('input[id="txtLogin"]').value = "user";
      document.querySelector('input[id="txtPassword"]').value = "pwd";
      document.querySelector('div[id="btnLogin"]').click();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not going to work in my case, I know this code you shared, the problem that I need to solve in my app is it needs to trigger keypress event from the input box.

Comment: And if you call `document.querySelector('input[id="txtLogin"]').onchange()` after changing the value it still does not work?